# Port 20 and 21 not open

Tags: vsftpd, serial-port

To run a wordpress website on Amazon EC2, I am using bitnami machine image.

To change the website, I need to set up a ftp server. I set up vsftpd using the following vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
listen=YES
listen_address=127.0.0.1
write_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_umask=022
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
seccomp_sandbox=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=52.14.106.23

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

The problem is that, port 20 and port 1024 - 1048 are not even open.

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-25-7:~$ netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:21            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50528           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::43109                :::*  


bitnami@ip-172-31-25-7:~$ nc -zv 127.0.0.1 20
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 20 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Any ftp connection attempt was rejected.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a "security group" where you specify that you open ports 20, 21 and range 1024-1048. Then you should add a security group to your EC2 Instance.

You can find security groups in AWS EC2 console on the left in the section "Network & Security".

Answer (score -1):

Your config file appears good.
Check the ports on your firewall.
Enable the ports via the firewall.
Check your machine and make sure you do not have any other ftp software installed as it can cause conflicts.

Comment: firewall? I did not set up any firewall. Where can I change firewall for EC2 instance? How could I let ftp server accept connection on port 20 and 1024 - 1048?

Comment: I do not have that specific info. Let's see if someone else can help. If I have the time later I will investigate.